# Fill Column with 1 Until Value Found, Then Repeat Fill with 0 Until Value Found Again

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
miniDF1 <- data.frame(Pred = c("A","A","B","A","B","B","C","A","B","C","A","A","A","A","B","A","C","B"))

    Pred
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     A
5     B
6     B
7     C
8     A
9     B
10    C
11    A
12    A
13    A
14    A
15    B
16    A
17    C
18    B
```

I am trying to make a new column filled with 1's until "C" is found in `Pred`, and then fill the new column with 0's until the next "C" is found, and repeat as such until the end of the DF. I have tried the following:

```
miniDF1 <- miniDF1 %>%
  mutate(Outcome = ifelse(str_detect(Pred, "C"), 1, 0)) %>% 
  fill(Outcome, .direction = 'up')

     Pred Outcome
1     A       0
2     A       0
3     B       0
4     A       0
5     B       0
6     B       0
7     C       1
8     A       0
9     B       0
10    C       1
11    A       0
12    A       0
13    A       0
14    A       0
15    B       0
16    A       0
17    C       1
18    B       0
```

but this is only putting 1's in the same row where there are "C's" located.

This is how it is expected to look like:

```
miniDF2 <- data.frame(Pred = c("A","A","B","A","B","B","C","A","B","C","A","A","A","A","B","A","C","B"),
                     Outcome = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0))

     Pred Outcome
1     A       1
2     A       1
3     B       1
4     A       1
5     B       1
6     B       1
7     C       1
8     A       0
9     B       0
10    C       0
11    A       1
12    A       1
13    A       1
14    A       1
15    B       1
16    A       1
17    C       1
18    B       0
```

I can't figure out how to get the values to flip accordingly, but I thought that that's what the `fill(Outcome, .direction = 'up')` part of my code was intended to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
miniDF1$Outcome <- cumsum(c(1, head(miniDF1$Pred == 'C', -1))) %% 2

miniDF1
   Pred Outcome
1     A       1
2     A       1
3     B       1
4     A       1
5     B       1
6     B       1
7     C       1
8     A       0
9     B       0
10    C       0
11    A       1
12    A       1
13    A       1
14    A       1
15    B       1
16    A       1
17    C       1
18    B       0
```

IN tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
miniDF1 %>%
  mutate(Outcome = cumsum(lag(Pred == 'C', default = TRUE)) %% 2)
```

Comment: In the tiydverse example, could you explain what the `%% 2` part does? Is it representing the `0` and `1`'s in the `Outcome` column? So that if it were to be `%% 3` would the column be filled with `0`, `1`, and `2`'s?

Comment: @samrizz4 yes, I am changing odd numbers to 1's and even numbers to 0

Answer (score 3):

Looks cumbersome but does what needed,

```
i1 <- which(miniDF1$Pred == 'C')
dd <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 0),v2 = c(i1[1], abs(diff(i1)), nrow(miniDF1)-max(i1)))

rep(dd$v1, dd$v2)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Maybe wrap it in a function too,

```
fun1 <- function(x, val){
  i1 <- which(x == val)
  dd <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 0),
                   v2 = c(i1[1], abs(diff(i1)), nrow(miniDF1)-max(i1)))
  return(rep(dd$v1, dd$v2))
}

miniDF1$outcome <- fun1(miniDF1$Pred, 'C')

#   Pred outcome
#1     A       1
#2     A       1
#3     B       1
#4     A       1
#5     B       1
#6     B       1
#7     C       1
#8     A       0
#9     B       0
#10    C       0
#11    A       1
#12    A       1
#13    A       1
#14    A       1
#15    B       1
#16    A       1
#17    C       1
#18    B       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try using `rleid` like

```
miniDF1$Outcome <- ifelse(data.table::rleid(miniDF1$Pred == "C") %% 4 %in% c(1,2), 1, 0)
miniDF1

   Pred Outcome
1     A       1
2     A       1
3     B       1
4     A       1
5     B       1
6     B       1
7     C       1
8     A       0
9     B       0
10    C       0
11    A       1
12    A       1
13    A       1
14    A       1
15    B       1
16    A       1
17    C       1
18    B       0
```

## explanation

For easier comparison, let's try `miniDF1$x <- rleid(miniDF1$Pred == "C")`.

```
   Pred Outcome x
1     A       1 1
2     A       1 1
3     B       1 1
4     A       1 1
5     B       1 1
6     B       1 1
7     C       1 2
8     A       0 3
9     B       0 3
10    C       0 4
11    A       1 5
12    A       1 5
13    A       1 5
14    A       1 5
15    B       1 5
16    A       1 5
17    C       1 6
18    B       0 7
```

You can see that `rleid`'s result change if `C` appears and next. Also, as you need to switch from `1` to `0` as `C` appears.

It means, if `x` is `1 and 2` or `3 and 4` or .... need to have `1`, `0`, `1`, and so on. So I divide `x` with 4 and get repeated `1 and 2`/ `3 and 0` values.

Comment: Could you explain what the `%% 4 %in% c(1,2)` part is doing? I'd assume c(1,2) is just the first and second columns but not sure where the 4 comes in.